# Why an unresolved reference on attempting to access constant values?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The app defines constants in a Kotlin singleton object:

```
@file:JvmName("APIConstants")
package com.myapp.api

object APIConstants {
    const val HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_NOT_AUTHORIZED = 401
    etc....
}
```

They are then used in another class:

```
import com.myapp.api.APIConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_NOT_AUTHORIZED
etc ...

class API {

    private fun returnBadResponse(response: Response<*>, callback: ApiAuthListener<*>) {
    if (response.code() == HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_NOT_AUTHORIZED) {
        callback.onBadAuthToken()
    } else {
        callback.onFailure(response.message(), getServerError(response))
    }
}
```

In this class Android Studio (3.0 beta) provided a hint to add the import for the constant, and it does not give any indication of a problem (no red underlines etc, and the constant reference in the method is shown in purple italic text indicating it has been resolved) but when I build the project I get this:

```
Error: Unresolved reference: HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

I've tried clearing the IDE cache and restarting it, and doing a clean build, which make no difference. I've tried removing the @JvmName annotation and even placing the const values in the root of the file with no containing object but neither allows a build.

Why is the class failing to reference the constant, especially when the IDE strongly suggests it can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

And the solution is.... to make very sure all Kotlin source files have a .kt file extension! In this case the APIConstants file was called "APIConstants" and not "APIConstants.kt" which appears to mean the IDE was able to resolve references based on the content of the file, but the build tools could not. Confusingly Android Studio showed a Kotlin K icon on the filename despite the lack of a .kt extension.